# Image not showing in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following code in my view:

```
<p>
<%= image_tag( "folder/"+"image_name.jpeg" ) %>
</p>
```

In development mode when I visit the server the image shows and its path is:

> http://localhost:3000/assets/folder/image_name-f562b410b0627f8099a44de48f5ee8fff6b1babf98dacfcf307a39a8b7fefbca.jpg

In production mode when I visit the page the image does not shows and its path is:

> domain/images/folder/image_name.jpeg

the image in the production site is in the following path:

> domain/assets/folder/image_name-f562b410b0627f8099a44de48f5ee8fff6b1babf98dacfcf307a39a8b7fefbca.jpg

Why does the link does not update automatically in the production mode like is updated in the development mode.

I already tried:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: can you correct your question? `"folder/"+image_name.jpeg` is not valid since image_name.jpeg is not a variable.

Comment: When you say "production mode", are you actually running on a production server? Or are you testing locally with `RAILS_ENV=production rails server`?

Comment: `The fingerprinting behavior is controlled by the config.assets.digest initialization option (which defaults to true).` From `http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production`. Can you check the value of `assets.digest` in your configuration from a console?

Comment: config.assets.digest is neither in the production.rb of development.rb configuration files.

Comment: i added config.assets.digest = true to both configuration files and it did not updated the image path...

Comment: I'm testing locally and deploying to cloud server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Not Working) Try in following order:

```
rails assets:clobber
rails assets:precompile
```

---

Try:

check whether config.assets.compile is set to true in config/environments/production.rb

Comment: check whether config.assets.compile is set to true in config/environments/production.rb:

Comment: config.assets.compile = false in config/environments/production.rb, should it be true?

Comment: Yep should be true

Comment: Thanks Ihtishaam! that did it!

Answer (score 1):

> I was able to solve this problem by changing:
>
> config.assets.compile = false to
>
> config.assets.compile = true
>
> in /config/environments/production.rb